# How to add a link in the end of each element (string) from the list? Using Thymeleaf

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I am fetching lines of text from the list one by one and I need to add a hyper link in the end of each line. Trying the code below, but link is not displayed.

```
    <p  th:each="releases : ${release}"
  class="releases" th:text="${releases}" th:href="www.abc.com"> New Releases </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a link to the end of each "release" string, you can use this:

```
<p th:each="releases : ${release}"
    class="releases">
    <span th:text="${releases}"></span>
    <a th:href="@{www.abc.com/${rel}(rel=${releases})}" 
       th:text=" '[link]'"></a>
</p>
```

So, for example, if the items in the release list are `Some_Release` and `Another_Release`, you will get this:

```
Some_Release [link]

Another_Release [link]
```

Each link text will have a customized href.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Actually I solved the problem similarly as in the last answer.

Comment: @IljaVeselov - You are always welcome to provide (and even accept) your own answer, explaining how you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p  th:each="releases : ${release}">  <span class="releases" th:text="${releases.split('Spotify')[0]}"> 
    New Releases </span> <a class="spoturl" th:href="${releases.split('URL:\s')[1]}"> Spotify URL </a> </p>
```

My solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p  th:each="releases : ${release}" th:href="www.abc.com"> <span class="releases" th:text="${releases}"> New Releases </span> </p>
```